# in SQLDeveloper, Build Where clause from excel sheet

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have spread sheet of one column has nearly half million records. To use that single column in a where clause, how smart or easily we can built? FYI - I'm using SQLDEV it allow only 1000 records in a single where clause.

Appreciate your help or suggestion.

Example :
Excel Column - SYS_ID
12
1
3
4
..
..
nearly half million sys_ID, i have to use this SYS_ID in a tableA in the where clause.

select * from tableA where sys_id in (12,1,3,4....)

Please suggest.

Comment: Import the values into a table and do a `JOIN` to it.

Answer (score 0):

In excel, in the next column over, put this formula:

```
="UNION ALL SELECT "&B1&"
```

(where B1 is the cell where the first value is)
fill that down.

Now create a table variable:

```
declare @sysid table (sysid int)
insert into @sysid
-- paste your excel result here
-- remove the first "union all" manually
```

now you can use :

```
select * from tableA INNER JOIN @sysid s on sys_id=sysid
```

Comment: thanks. this is not going work. Any other better way please? somewhere i read in online this solution - "Range Scan" any thought on this? Build where clause like this in ((1,1st sys_id), (1,2nd sys_id), (1,3rd sys_id), (1,4th sys_id))

Comment: Thanks. the above solution didnt work. Any other suggestion. Please help